# Kubernetes getting same request multiple time

Tags: java, api, kubernetes

I've kubernetes cluster and My application is working on one pod. My application create some files and it sometimes took over than 5 min. and  when it took so long pod create same request. I checked everywhere but actually I don't know how to search this problem it might releated with timeout or some thing like this but I'am sure it is releated with kubernetes. I've tried same application on docker container and I didn't see same problem in there. I'll be greatfull if you anyone help me. (kubernetes version is v1.18.5)

My expectation is get request only one time.

Comment: wow `v1.18.5`, Are you using a readiness probe?

Comment: Yes I'm using readiness probe but This files not creating when pod is starting. You should request to the api and when get this request it is dublicated after a while it creates same request again.